# Making a strongly named COM interop assembly with a PFX file

Tags: com, interop, cryptography, com-interop, public-key-encryption

I am trying to create a strongly named COM interop assembly with a PFX file.
TlbImp.exe is perfectly happy with an SNK file created using "sn.exe -k" (which contains both public and private keys), but the problem is that I have a PFX file...
I can export the public key from PFX to SNK using sn.exe -p, but it only exports the public key, which TlbImp.exe does not like at all. Can I export both public and private keys?
I tried to install the PFX file using 
sn.exe -i MyCompany.pfx xyz 
and then import the type library using 
TlbImp.exe /keycontainer:xyz ...", 
but that gives me 
TlbImp : error TI0000 : Invalid strong name parameters specified.

What can I do?
Thank you!

**UPDATE**: Oleg's answer and his utility below work perfectly. 
The PFX file (after it is re-exported) can be successfully used to extract the 
public key (*sn.exe -p*) to be used it with tlbimp.exe (*tlbimp.exe  
/publickey:xyz.pub*). The PFX file can then be used to re-sign the interop 
dll (*sn.exe -R*)

Comodo really did drop the ball on this one. Below is the dump (*certutil.exe 
-dump -v xyz.pfx*) of the original and fixed PFX files:

**Before:**

CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID(2):
Key Container = {36BDD7BD-F295-47B2-B9E7-C25BD5B4313E}
Unique container name: 
bf63afd9ba3fb912ccd3423c6486e5fc_25e0623f-f712-49e2-abda-f31f014b5dae
Provider = Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0
ProviderType = 1
Flags = 0
**KeySpec = 1 -- AT_KEYEXCHANGE**
...
Private Key:
PRIVATEKEYBLOB
Version: 2
**aiKeyAlg: 0xa400**
**CALG_RSA_KEYX**
Algorithm Class: **0xa000(5) ALG_CLASS_KEY_EXCHANGE**
Algorithm Type: 0x400(2) ALG_TYPE_RSA
Algorithm Sub-id: 0x0(0) ALG_SID_RSA_ANY

**After:**

CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID(2):
Key Container = {DBA6454E-F6D2-4F0B-AB1B-9E4F7C0E139C}
Unique container name: 
d2d09f87081c1af7c4225889f1af2250_25e0623f-f712-49e2-abda-f31f014b5dae
Provider = Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0
ProviderType = 1
Flags = 0
**KeySpec = 2 -- AT_SIGNATURE**
...
Private Key:
PRIVATEKEYBLOB
Version: 2
**aiKeyAlg: 0x2400**
**CALG_RSA_SIGN**
Algorithm Class: **0x2000(1) ALG_CLASS_SIGNATURE**
Algorithm Type: 0x400(2) ALG_TYPE_RSA
Algorithm Sub-id: 0x0(0) ALG_SID_RSA_ANY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to do the following

```
sn.exe -p MyCompany.pfx MyCompany.pub
tlbimp.exe My.dll /delaysign /publickey:MyCompany.pub /out:Interop.My.dll
sn.exe -R Interop.My.dll MyCompany.pfx
```

If you create primary interop assembly from tlb file of a COM DLL you will `tlbimp.exe` in the form

```
tlbimp.exe My.tlb /primary /delaysign /publickey:MyCompany.pub /out:Interop.My.dll
```

You can additionally use code signing of the interop assembly:

```
signtool.exe sign /f MyCompany.pfx /p password /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll /v Interop.My.dll
```

**UPDATED**: I found *the reason* of your problem which you has. First of all I should explain (or remind) about one feature of the key container.

The private key exist in the *key container*. The key container can be on the local hard disk in some file from the folder `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\YourUserSid`. In the same way the key container can be the part of PFX file. In both cases **one key container can save up to two private keys: one for digital signature (`AT_SIGNATURE`) and another for key exchange (`AT_KEYEXCHANGE`)**. You can look through parameters of [CryptGenKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function for more details. Both keys can be absolutely different. For example you can hold in the digital signature of one key container private key of the size 4096 and in the key exchange part of the same container *another* private key of the size 2048.

The certificate has `CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID` as one from its [certificate extended property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376523%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It save the [CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure which `dwKeySpec` (with the value `AT_SIGNATURE`, `AT_KEYEXCHANGE` or some other like `AT_KEYEXCHANGE | AT_SIGNATURE`) field are used together with other fields `pwszContainerName` (`le-fe9728d2-af26-4f15-9be0-48c5af6f21dc` for example), `pwszProvName` ("Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0" for example), `dwProvType` (`PROV_RSA_FULL` for example). So one has full reference to the key from the certificate.

The problem is that **the certificate which you have has the key saved in the key exchange part of the container and not in the digital signature part**. It make no problem in case of usage of `SignTool.exe` tool, but in case of the usage `tlbimp.exe` you get the error

> TlbImp : error TI1000 : The type library importer encountered an
>   unexpected exception: System.Security.SecurityException - Invalid
>   assembly public key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141E)

I suppose that it's common problem of Comodo or probably Comodo certificates which one get from through Tucows.

```
CN = UTN-USERFirst-Object
OU = http://www.usertrust.com
O = The USERTRUST Network
L = Salt Lake City
S = UT
C = US
```

To reproduce the problem which I describe you can do the following steps:

1) Create key pair, save it in the key exchange of the new key container and create self-signed certificate which you the key pair. We can use for example the following parameter of `MakeCert.exe` to do this:

> MakeCert.exe -pe -ss MY -a sha1 -cy authority -len 2048 -e 12/31/2020
>   -r -n "CN=My Company Root Authority,O=My Company,C=DE" -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 -sky exchange -len 2048 -sk myKeyContainer

In the above example we save the new key in the key container with explicit specified name `'myKeyContainer'` to make easier to find and examine it in the future. In practice one don't specify the parameter and the container name will be generated automatically based on new GUID.

2) Use "Certificates" Snap-In to export from MMC.EXE the new created certificate as PFX file. You have to choose a password during the export. Alternatively you can use `CertUtil.exe` to do the same.

> CertUtil.exe -privatekey -user -exportpfx -p yourPassword "My Company Root
>   Authority" MyCompany.pfx

3) Export public part of the key in the SNK format. I prefer to use .PUB extension instead of .SNK to distinguish it more clear from the .SNK file holding the key pair. One can use `sn.exe` with -p parameter to do this:

> sn.exe -p MyCompany.pfx MyCompany.pub

4) Now one can use `tlbimp.exe` to reproduce the error.

> tlbimp.exe My.tlb /machine:X86 /primary /delaysign
>   /publickey:MyCompany.pub /out:Interop.My.dll

If you would not use the switch `-sky exchange` at the first step the usage of `tlbimp.exe` will be successfully and you could use in the next step

> sn.exe -R Interop.My.dll MyCompany.pfx

to sign the `Interop.My.dll`. After that you can use code signing to dll additionally

> signtool.exe sign /f MyCompany.pfx /p yourPassword /t
>   http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll /v Interop.My.dll

Sorry for the long text, but I want be sure that people who will have the same problem will be able to understand it.

To solve the problem you need use any tool which can export and import private key. You should export the key from the key exchange part of the container and import it in the same container in the digital signature part. If you would have problem to find the corresponding tool I can try help. I don't know existing tools very good, but I know many ways how to write program which do this. In case of .NET I would use [ExportCspBlob](http://ExportCspBlob) to export the key and use [ImportCspBlob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.importcspblob.aspx) to import it back. One should change only one bit in the key blob to use `AT_SIGNATURE` instead of AT_KEYEXCHANGE. If you open the key container you should use `KeyNumber.Exchange` once as `CspParameters.KeyNumber` parameter and `KeyNumber.Signature` in the next step.

**UPDATED 2**: I found [here](http://www.jensign.com/JavaScience/dotnet/keyinfo/index.html) description which corresponds my assumptions. One workaround which are suggested is to set `REG_DWORD` value with the name `KeySpec` and the value 2 (`AT_SIGNATURE`) in the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\StrongName`. I tested this, but it's not help for the usage of `tlbimp.exe`.

So I just wrote the utility which do all the work. You should import your PFX file and then start my utility `ChangeKeyProvInfo.exe` with the certificate Issue name. For example

```
ChangeKeyProvInfo.exe "Dmitry Streblechenko"
```

After that I add the digital signature part in the key container with the same private key as has the key exchange part. Then I change the property of the certificate to use the digital signature part of the key container.

You can download the utility [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/ChangeKeyProvInfo.exe) and [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/ChangeKeyProvInfo.c) the source code.

To make easier to find the code I post it also below. You should see the code only as the quick and dirty solution which I wrote today, so the code is not perfect.

```c
#define STRICT

#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "Crypt32.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, LPCTSTR *argv)
{
    HCERTSTORE hStore = NULL;
    PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext = NULL;
    LPCTSTR pszCertSubjectName = NULL;
    BOOL bSuccess, bResult = FALSE;
    DWORD cbData = 0, dwKeySpec = 0;
    HCRYPTKEY hKey = 0, hKeyNew = 0;
    BOOL fCallerFreeProvOrNCryptKey;
    PBYTE pPrivateKeyBlob = NULL;
    PUBLICKEYSTRUC *pPublicKey = NULL;
    HCRYPTPROV_OR_NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hCryptProvOrNCryptKey = 0;
    PCRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO pKeyProvInfo = NULL;

    if (argc != 2) {
        _tprintf(TEXT("USAGE:\r\n\tChangeKeyProvInfo.exe CertSubjectName\n"));
        return 1;
    }
    pszCertSubjectName = argv[1];

    __try {
        hStore = CertOpenStore (CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 
            X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
            (HCRYPTPROV_LEGACY)0,
            CERT_STORE_ENUM_ARCHIVED_FLAG | CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG | CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER,
            TEXT("MY"));
        if (hStore == NULL) {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Error in CertOpenStore(): %d"), GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }

        pCertContext = CertFindCertificateInStore (hStore,
            X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
            0,
            CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR,
            pszCertSubjectName,
            NULL);
        if (pCertContext == NULL) {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Error in CertFindCertificateInStore(): %d"), GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }

        bSuccess = CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(pCertContext,
            CRYPT_ACQUIRE_COMPARE_KEY_FLAG | CRYPT_ACQUIRE_NO_HEALING,
            NULL,
            &hCryptProvOrNCryptKey,
            &dwKeySpec,
            &fCallerFreeProvOrNCryptKey);
        if (!bSuccess) {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Error in CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(): %d"), GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }

        bSuccess = CryptGetUserKey (hCryptProvOrNCryptKey, dwKeySpec, &hKey);
        if (!bSuccess) {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Error in CryptGetUserKey(): %d"), GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }

        // get privale key as clear text data in form PRIVATEKEYBLOB
        cbData = 0;
        bSuccess = CryptExportKey (hKey, 0, PRIVATEKEYBLOB, 0, NULL, &cbData);
        if (!bSuccess) {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Error in CryptExportKey(): %d"), GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }

        pPrivateKeyBlob = (PBYTE)LocalAlloc(LPTR, cbData);
        if (pPrivateKeyBlob == NULL) {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Error in LocalAlloc(): %d"), GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }

        bSuccess = CryptExportKey (hKey, 0, PRIVATEKEYBLOB, 0, pPrivateKeyBlob, &cbData);
        if (!bSuccess) {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Error in CryptExportKey(): %d"), GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }

        // the PRIVATEKEYBLOB started with the PUBLICKEYSTRUC which contains the KeyAlg
        // CALG_RSA_KEYX are used for AT_KEYEXCHANGE
        // CALG_RSA_SIGN are used for AT_SIGNATURE
        pPublicKey = (PUBLICKEYSTRUC *)pPrivateKeyBlob;
        if (pPublicKey->aiKeyAlg == CALG_RSA_SIGN) {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Currently AT_SIGNATURE are used - nothing to do.\n"));
            __leave;
        } else if (pPublicKey->aiKeyAlg != CALG_RSA_KEYX) {
            _tprintf(TEXT("ERROR: Unknown algorithm 0x%X are used\n"), pPublicKey->aiKeyAlg);
            __leave;
        }

        // !!!!!! the next line in the most important !!!!!!
        pPublicKey->aiKeyAlg = CALG_RSA_SIGN; 
        bSuccess = CryptImportKey (hCryptProvOrNCryptKey, pPrivateKeyBlob, cbData, (HCRYPTKEY)NULL, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &hKeyNew);
        if (!bSuccess) {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Error in CertGetCertificateContextProperty(): %d"), GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }
        _tprintf(TEXT("The key container has successfully imported the same key for the AT_SIGNATURE usage.\n"));

        bSuccess = CertGetCertificateContextProperty (pCertContext, CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID, 0, &cbData);
        if (!bSuccess) {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Error in CertGetCertificateContextProperty(): %d"), GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }
        pKeyProvInfo = (PCRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO)LocalAlloc (LPTR, cbData);
        if (pKeyProvInfo == NULL) {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Error in LocalAlloc(): %d"), GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }

        bSuccess = CertGetCertificateContextProperty (pCertContext, CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID, pKeyProvInfo, &cbData);
        if (!bSuccess) {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Error in CertGetCertificateContextProperty(): %d"), GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }
        // !!!!!! the next line in the most important !!!!!!
        pKeyProvInfo->dwKeySpec = AT_SIGNATURE;
        bSuccess = CertSetCertificateContextProperty (pCertContext, CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID, CERT_SET_PROPERTY_IGNORE_PERSIST_ERROR_FLAG, pKeyProvInfo);
        if (!bSuccess) {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Error in CertSetCertificateContextProperty(): %d"), GetLastError());
            __leave;
        }
        _tprintf(TEXT("The certificale property was successfully changed to use the key with AT_SIGNATURE.\n"));
        bResult = TRUE;
    }
    __finally {
        if (pPrivateKeyBlob)
            pPrivateKeyBlob = (PBYTE) LocalFree (pPrivateKeyBlob);

        if (pKeyProvInfo)
            pKeyProvInfo = (PCRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO) LocalFree (pKeyProvInfo);

        if (pCertContext)
            bSuccess = CertFreeCertificateContext (pCertContext);

        if (hKeyNew)
            bSuccess = CryptDestroyKey (hKeyNew);

        if (hCryptProvOrNCryptKey)
            bSuccess = CryptReleaseContext (hCryptProvOrNCryptKey, 0);

        if (hStore)
            bSuccess = CertCloseStore (hStore, CERT_CLOSE_STORE_CHECK_FLAG);
    }

    return bResult? 0: 1;
}
```

**UPDATED 2**: [Here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/ChangeKeyProvInfo.txt) you can download full protocol of an experiment which everybody can repeat to reproduce the problem how I understand if. The first certificate saved in the [My.pfx](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/My.pfx) can be analysed with respect of `certutil.exe -dump -v My.pfx`. The full output you can see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/My-pfx.txt). The most important part of the output is:

```
...
  CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID(2):
    ...
    KeySpec = 1 -- AT_KEYEXCHANGE

...
Private Key:
  PRIVATEKEYBLOB
  Version: 2
  aiKeyAlg: 0xa400
    CALG_RSA_KEYX
    Algorithm Class: 0xa000(5) ALG_CLASS_KEY_EXCHANGE
...
Encryption test passed
```

The modified certificates will be saved in [My1.pfx](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/My1.pfx). [The output](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/My1%28fixed%29-pfx.txt) of the `certutil.exe -dump -v My.pfx` shows that the problem is fixed:

```
...
  CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID(2):
    ...
    KeySpec = 2 -- AT_SIGNATURE

...
Private Key:
  PRIVATEKEYBLOB
  Version: 2
  aiKeyAlg: 0x2400
    CALG_RSA_SIGN
    Algorithm Class: 0x2000(1) ALG_CLASS_SIGNATURE
...
Signature test passed
```

**UPDATE 3:**
After 3 years, the problem with Comodo signatures is still present. Below is their response. Next time my certificate needs to be renewed, I will go with somebody else.

---

Our Code Signing certificates are intended to be used for Microsoft Authenticode signatures (and other object-signing related items; e.g. jar signing) and are not quite intended for Microsoft Strong Name signing for assemblies. If Microsoft's application won't use a keypair with the keySpec set to their suggested default (1, AT_KEYEXCHANGE; which allows both signing and encryption) and only works with AT_SIGNATURE (only allows signing), then it would be to be a processing problem with Microsoft's utility and you would need to open a case with Microsoft to correct the issue. We have hundreds of thousands of customers that are able to apply Microsoft Authenticode & other object related signatures without issue with this keySpec set as-is. We are unwilling to modify a process that is working flawlessly for virtually everyone aside from a handful of individuals who wish to go the extreme and use a publicly trusted CA to strongName sign their assemblies. Most developers that we encounter do not use a CA signed certificate for Strong Name signing assemblies, but rather do so with a self-signed certificate due to maximum term limits that public CAs impose on all certs (no more than 3-5 years max.)

Based on the stackoverflow post, you have created a utility that corrects & does provide you with a workaround to your specific issue so unfortunately there would be nothing further that we can advise upon in this matter.

We apologize for the inconvenience.

Kind Regards,

Technical Support

Comment: I thought that /delaysign simply created a placeholder that needed to be replaced later with a real key. Am I wrong?

Comment: I get an error. Only the public key is exported, so the PUB file length is 288 bytes; all other SNK files are twice as big<br>Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Type Library to Assembly Converter 2.0.50727.42
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

TlbImp : error TI0000 : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException - Bad Length. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090004)

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: It place additionally the public key in the assembly. You can use IL Disassembler (ildasm.exe) from the SDK tools to open the assembly dll and then double click on the MANIFEST. In the window which will be displayed you will find `.publickey`. Exactly the section will be placed in the interop assembly by `tlbimp.exe /delaysign ...` Later you can sign the assembly with `MyCompany.pfx` file. The person who use `sn.exe` should know password of PFX. So the usage of `MyCompany.pub` (`MyCompanyPubkey.snk`) by every developer has security advantage.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: In what situation you have the error? What you try to do at all? Do you compile assembly which should be strong assembly and be used as COM from not .NET application? Or you has COM DLL and you want use it from .NET. So you create interop assembly which you want to use in your .NET application? Do you use Visual Studio?

Comment: Oleg, I have a COM dll (written in Delphi) and I import the type library (TLB). If I do not use /publickey, I can create the interop dll just fine. If I use a one-off SNK file, it gets generated just fine. It it only when export the key from the PFX file (288 bytes as opposed to the normal 596 bytes size), tlbimp fails with the "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException - Bad Length. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090004)" error.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: Do you have separate .TLB file? If not, you can open the DLL file as resource and export resource of the type `TYPELIB` (typically with the name `1`) in `My.tlb` file. I can do this with Visual Studio. Then I can use `tlbimp.exe My.tlb /primary /delaysign /publickey:MyCompany.pub /out:Interop.My.dll` with `MyCompany.pub` having public key only to create primary interop assembly. I tried it just now. I had no "Bad Length" error.

Comment: Oleg, yes, I do have the TLB file, and I can delay sign the generated interop dll using a test key (snk file of 596 bytes). But when I try to replace the placeholder using "sn.exe -R", it complains that "Key pair does not match public key from assembly". The problem is extracting the public key from my PFX file in the format that tlbimp.exe will like. "sn.exe -p" extracts the key into a file of length 288 bytes, and tlbimp.exe does not like that file. I am getting desperate... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: Sorry, but I can't reproduce your experiments. If I did all the steps which I described above and can see `Assembly 'Interop.My.dll' successfully re-signed`. Could you provide URL with the tlb file and I'll try to create primary interop with my PFX?

Comment: Oleg, sure, I can do that. Where do you want me to send the TLB file to? My e-mail is dmitry at dimastr dot com. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: You can download two test TLB here: [FirstComObj.tlb](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/FirstComObj.tlb), [T2USvc.tlb](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/T2USvc.tlb) and [MyCompany.pub](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/MyCompany.pub). You can use `tlbimp.exe FirstComObj.tlb /primary /delaysign /machine:X86 /publickey:MyCompany.pub /out:Interop.FirstComObj.dll` to generate primary assembly. (You can't sign it of cause.) If it will not work on your computer you should verify **which version of tlbimp.exe you use**. I'll send you email too.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: I personally used the `tlbimp.exe` in all my tests which displayed "Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Type Library to Assembly Converter 4.0.30319.1" in the first line of the output.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: I think that I found the reason of your problem. See "UPDATED" part of my answer.

Comment: @Oleg should ChangeKeyProvInfo.exe parameter be certificate Issuer name or Subject name? You mentioned certificate issuer but CertFindCertificateInStore is called with CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR dwFindType parameter. In my case those 2 do not match.

Comment: @Oleg I imported pfx file. Below is some output: `certutil -store my my ================ Certificate 0 ================ Serial Number: 769619706bb4c875b5e6e5159a2b8fcd Issuer: CN=COMODO Code Signing CA, O=COMODO CA Limited, L=Salford, S=Greater Man chester, C=GB NotBefore: 7/26/2011 1:00 AM NotAfter: 7/26/2013 12:59 AM Subject: CN=Encryptomatic LLC, O=Encryptomatic LLC ...` When I run `ChangeKeyProvInfo.exe "Encryptomatic LLC"` I get `Error in CertFindCertificateInStore(): -2146885628`. I also tried "COMODO Code Signing CA" and "COMODO CA Limited" as cmd params. Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: @VeljaRadenkovic: It should be subject name like "Encryptomatic LLC". You should import the certificate (from the PFX file) in the current user certificate store.

Comment: @Oleg I thought I did that by executing: `certutil -f -p SomePassword -importpfx encryptomatic-codesign-2011.pfx
Certificate "CN=Encryptomatic LLC, O=Encryptomatic LLC, STREET=16299 Sugar Islan
d Road, L=Audubon, S=MN, PostalCode=56511, C=US" added to store.

**CertUtil: -importPFX command completed successfully**.`

Am I still wrong somewhere?

Comment: @VeljaRadenkovic: I don't know your exact situation, but if you has an error you should verify every stop. For example you should start mmc.exe add Certificate snap-in, choose current user and verify that the certificate is correctly imported.

Comment: @Oleg thanks for the tip. I was missing -user cmd switch. Utility worked excellent. Thanks for all work around this issue.
Just for the record: To import certificate from pfx file to current user store command needs -user switch i.e. `certutil -user -p SomePassword -importpfx encryptomatic-codesign-2011.pfx`